# Is It Possible To Get The Currency Of country using the user IP in .net core?

Tags: .net-core

Is It Possible To Get The Currency Of country using the user's IP ?
like $ Or EURO OR LE
I Have Tried This  https://usercountry.com/  But still Not Working

Answer (score 0):

What problem you found using usercountry.com (ipstack.com)? Have you tried to perform a request to

```
https://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
```

and then parse the output using any JSON parser lib (e.g. System.Text.Json)?

There's a documentation here: [IPStack Documentation](https://ipstack.com/documentation)